# Nagios check all instances with check_mssql_health

Tags: sql-server, nagios

How do I make Nagios check all instances of SQL Server with `check_mssql_health`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried the following?

Connecting with the perl Sybase module can be somewhat tricky.
I finally got a succesfull connection this way:

```
1 - Edit /etc/freetds/freetds.conf

[sqlhost1]
host = 192.168.1.1
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0

2 - Use the --server command line option instead of the --hostname option:

check_mssql_health --server=sqlhost1 --username=nagiosuser --password=nagiospass --mode connected-users
```

Comment: Yeah, already tried that.. I'll back to work only on monday then I'll try again and I'll let you know the results.. thank you anyway!!

Comment: No problem.Thanks for voting as well.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, would you please check this answer as a solution?